# Is it possible to use Kitkat's WebView in lower version using support library

Tags: android

I am facing some issues on webview in Android OS version <4.4 like:

Anchor tag doesn't work if webview height is wrap_content etc.

Is it possible to use Kitkat's WebView in lower version using support library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably not. Short of recompiling Android there's no way to use the a different implementation of the Webkit underlying WebView.

I'm afraid the only solution to the various differences and drawbacks is to address them case-by-case, probably within the HTML, Javascript and/or CSS.